# Switch case doesn't call the functions inside them

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The problem is that `case`s don't call the functions inside them. Why don't the switch case call the functions inside them?

```
void admin_menu()
{

system("cls");
int x;

cin >> x;
switch (x)
{
    case '1':
        write_student();
        break;

    case '2':
       return;

    default:
        cout << "\a";
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'1'` has a type of char, not `int`, but you read `int`s. So you have a wrong comparison inside the `switch` statement: `'1'` and `'2'` are converted to `int` before being compared to `x`, so the result is not what you have expected.

If you read `int`s, then the `switch` should be:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 1:
        write_student();
        break;

    case 2:
       return;

    default:
        std::cout << "\a";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your *constant_expression* in `case` label is a character literal. It will be promoted / converted to `int` as `x` is of type `int`. Characters have underlying integer values and are implicitly convertible to integers. The character literal of `'1'` corresponds to an integral value of `49` and character literal of `'2'` corresponds to integral value of `50`. So effectively with your code you have (assuming ASCII encoding):

```
switch (x)
{
    case 49:
        write_student();
        break;

    case 50:
       return;
//
```

Remove the single quotes and use integral literals instead of character literals:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 1:
        write_student();
        break;

    case 2:
       return;
//
```

For more info explore the [switch statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) reference.

Comment: Would be even better if you didn’t assume a specific encoding. C++ doesn’t.

Comment: By the way it doesn’t really matter if the types of the case labels are different: the normal rules of argument promotion will kick in.